# How to send SMS using node.js without using a provider like Twilio

Tags: node.js, sms

I want to make a web app designed to send SMS via web interface.
How can I send SMS (from my phone number) to specified recipient using node/express.

Is it possible to do so without using a provider like Twilio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there are some very particular functionalities your mobile carrier is providing, there is nothing like "send SMS (from my phone number) ... using node/express".

Only the phone that has your SIM installed within can send SMS from your number.

#### Possible solutions

- If you are only interested in sending SMS from a web platform, use a provider like SendGrid and Twilio
- If you need to send SMS from a phone number assigned to a physical SIM owned by you, devices exist that can be connected to your server, will host your SIM, and allow you to send messages.
- If you need to send SMS from your phone number (and be able to use your number at the same time) you may create a mobile app that regularly downloads updates from your server and send the listed messages.